# ODBC call failed. generic failure.

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

Ive recently being trying to connect the back end of a MYsql database to the front end of MS Access 2007-2010.

Ive downloaded the oracle MySQL ODBC Connector but it just wont seem to connect.

The failure message is very generic, Is there anyway of finding out exactly why the connection is failing.

Comment: You did not provide enough info. Can you connect to MySQL server using another client? Did you create ODBC source (unless you use DSN-less connection)?

Comment: Even if you think the error message is not helpful, posting it here might provide us with a clue of what's happening.

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit? BTW http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql is often helpful.

Comment: im using 32 bit. The message says ODBC - call failed

Comment: i did create a ODBC source

Comment: Still, can you connect to MySQL server using another client, like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)? Also, what OS are you using? Is it Windows XP or Windows 7?